# ssh: port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, macos

I have a question regarding remote access a machine via `ssh`. I'm trying to ssh into my linux machine from my mac and I've already setup the ssh-server on my ubuntu and opened the port 22. However, I got these error message while trying to connect:

```
[@Ges-MacBook ~]->ssh <username>@<remote machine's ipv4> -vvv 
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for * 
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <remote machine's ipv4> is address 
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/geyan/.ssh/known_hosts' 
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/geyan/.ssh/known_hosts2' 
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling 
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering 
debug1: Connecting to <remote machine's ipv4> [<remote machine's ipv4>] port 22. 
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48 
debug1: connect to address <remote machine's ipv4> port 22: Connection refused 
ssh: connect to host <remote machine's ipv4> port 22: Connection refused
```

What's the problem here and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: It is totally telling you the connection is refused. My knee-jerk reaction is that you need to verify that the ssh daemon is running and listening on the Linux machine. You can do that with netstat, for example.

Comment: Depending on how the remote machine network is configured double check your firewall/portforwarding as well... is there a firewall infront of the machine, besides the built-in Ubuntu firewall?

Comment: Does `ssh localhost` work for your Linux PC **locally**?

Comment: yes, `ssh localhost` works fine

Comment: It most likely means you have **not** actually opened the port in your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by the port being blocked by the firewall. I suggest you try using uncomplicated firewall. It is an easy to use interface for the more complicated `iptables`.

`sudo ufw status`

If ufw is inactive.

`sudo ufw enable`

If ufw status is active, then you should also see whether or not the port's 'Action' state's allow or deny. If the action is listed as deny try:

`sudo ufw allow 22`

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-firewall